# IIS logging: don't write to log entry if match specific condition

Tags: iis, configuration, logging

i'm looking for some way to avoid logging some specific files like

/WebResource.axd and /ScriptResource.axd

is there any way to write some code lines in Global.asa or add some configurations to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, logging happens inside of IIS and not in the ASP.Net layer.